# NSLocalizedString não retorna texto correspondente

Tags: objective-c, xcode

**Pessoal**

Estou usando a função `NSLocalizedString` em um app para iOS mas este não está retornando o texto referente que coloquei em um arquivo `Localization.strings` que tem o conteúdo abaixo. Alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver isto?

```
label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"MEDICO", nil);
```

**Arquivo**:

```
/* 
  Localization.strings
  Hexapod

  Created by Celso Melero on 08/06/15.
  Copyright (c) 2015 inArts Studio. All rights reserved.
*/

/* Médico */
"MEDICO" = "Doctor";
```

Comment: Pode colocar o que está aparecendo na tela no componente `label`?

Comment: iTSanga, a resposta abaixo resolveu o problema. A nome do arquivo estava errado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro certifique que você seleciou os idiomas que você irá dar suporte em seu projeto:

[image: Idiomas suportados]

Segundo certifique que você está utilizando o nome correto para o arquivo de localização, ele deve ser nomeado `Localizable.strings` e não `Localization.strings` como você colocou na pergunta:

[image: Arquivos de localização]

Comment: Muito obrigado. O nome do arquivo estava errado mesmo.